# QT5 Android not Packing Versioned SharedObject

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk, cross-compiling, qt5

I'm having a problem with QT5 and Android. I am trying to use a cross-build of libpurple (thanks GoogleSummerOfCode), but it is not packing it to the apk and Java throws

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1496): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1937]: 1725 could not load needed library 'libpurple.so.20' for 'libSimpleChat.so' (load_library[1092]: Library 'libpurple.so.20' not found)
```

The `libpurple.so.20` is a symlink to `libpurple.so.20.0`, renaming does not change anything, if I copy this link in the android `lib` folder it is ignored (only `.so` libs are packaged). Even if i rename it to `libpurple.so`, it does not work because `libpurple.so.20` seems to be hardcoded in a binary.

Comment: What have you got in your android/res/values/libs.xml for the bundled_libs?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem and solved by re-compiling shared library with non-versioned soname.

Check the soname of the shared library:

```
$objdump -x libpurple.so | g 'SONAME'
```

You should see something like:

```
SONAME    libpurple.so.20
```

Rebuild library and give a non-versioned soname:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -shared -fPIC .... \
    -Wl,-soname,libpurple.so -o libpurple.so
```

Now the shared library should have a non-versioned soname.

```
$objdump -x libpurple.so | g 'SONAME'
    SONAME    libpurple.so
```

When you link this shared library with your own library, it will use non-versioned library name.

```
$objdump -x libSimpleChat.so | g 'NEED'
    NEEDED    libpurple.so
```